# Doesn't implement interface of IDatabaseIntializer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I using the interface of `System.Data.Entity.IDatabaseIntializer`, it always says that it doesn't implement the interface.

```
namespace ImageSharingWithAuth.DAL
{
    public class ImageSharingDB : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }   
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }   
        public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }    
        public ImageSharingDB() : base("DefaultConnection") { }   
    }
}


namespace ImageSharingWithAuth.DAL
{
    public class ImageSharingDBInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<ImageSharingDB>
    {
        public void IntializeDatabase(ImageSharingDB db)
        {
            if (db.Database.Exists())
            {
                db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("alter database ImageSharingWithAuth set single_user with rollback immediate");
                db.Database.Delete();
            }
            db.Database.Create();   
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(
                "DefaultConnection",
                "Users",
                "Id",
                "UserId",
                autoCreateTables: true);
            this.Seed(db);
        }
        protected void Seed(ImageSharingDB db)
        {......
```

The interface should be `System.Data.Entity.IDatabaseIntializer<in TContext>` where `TContext: DbContext`, and the `ImageSharingDB` do is the `DbContext`, so I think that the `ImageSharingDBInitializer` should implement the `IDatabaseIntializer`.

However, .Net throws an error:

> error CS0535: 'ImageSharingWithAuth.DAL.ImageSharingDBInitializer'does not implement
>   interface member System.Data.Entity.IDatabaseInitializer.InitializeDatabase(ImageSharingWithAuth.DAL.ImageSharingDB)'

Answer (score 0):

It should be In-i-tializeDatabase but you have In-tializeDatabase.

Answer (score 0):

If you want be sure that your class implement all contracts from interface, click right on the name of interface (`public class className: interfaceName`) and choose Implement interface. Of course you have to implement generate methods :)